# Create a printable document from template

Tags: views

I am fairly new to Drupal. I have a Microsoft Word Document template and would like to allow users to fill in fields and insert an image and then print the document. I am not stuck on using the Word template if that is not feasible.

We have been using a document that is a fillable form. We fill out the fields and then have to add an image to the form in a particular position. I would like, if possible, to have Drupal do this. I would like it so a use goes to the site, fills out the information and uploads the image. Once that is done they would need to print the document and have it retain a specific layout.

Possible? Please point me in the right direction. I am using Drupal 7.x

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This use-case is perfectly normal for Drupal, but you're better off not using Word at all.

- Create a content type (let's call it `fillable`) that contains all of the fields you require including an Image field which requires the [ImageField](https://www.drupal.org/project/imagefield) module.
- Give your users the '`fillable`: Create new content' and any of the other relevant permissions for that content type that you wish them to be able to do.
- Edit the content type and go to the `manage display` tab, determine how you want the fields to show (with labels? as links?).  If you need to group fields you can use the [Field collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection) module.
- Use your theme to make the node page layout how you want it to be
- Put a print.css file in your theme and use that to fine-tune how the document prints

If you want to make other changes to the output of the node (like extra text in certain places, or complicated formatting), you can create a [node template](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.tpl.php/7) for that specific content type by giving it a name such as node--fillable.tpl.php